# How can i Unfold UV in one axis (horizontal) like Maya Unfold

Tags: uv

Can i unfold UV directly in one axis? Not scale. [image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps pressing "U" > "Project From View" might help you here?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case this makes a difference, forgive me if I've missed the point..

'Follow Active Quads' refers to active quads in **UV space**.

Here's an object that produces non-orthogonal UVs when unwrapped cylindrically:
(The cylindrical projection is view-dependent, you want the poles aligned to screen Y and the equator along screen X)

[image]

The quad at the bottom left of the UV has been straightened, by scaling or snapping, and left active.

Now going back into the 3D View and <kbd>U</kbd> unwrapping again, with 'Follow Active Quads' and the 'Even' option, aligns the UV.

[image]

This could have been a selection of faces, rather than all of them, if that's what's needed.

Comment: I don't think he necessarily wants to use the 'Even' option, as some of his circumferential face loops have different widths. It's easy enough to try with Length Average/Length though. Will this technique work for him where he has triangles instead of quads?

Comment: @Rekov Yup, I'm unclear about the exact problem .. and.. no, FAQ only works on quad loops.. so this answer may be useless ...